# Using dependency injection in a Game of Life to inject new rules

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I have a course project that is a refactor of Game of Life in Scala. It's a 
simple pure Scala + SBT project. One of my tasks is to extract the game logic 
from `GameEngine` class and make easier to add new rules, as Conway, Highlife or
anything like that. I turned `GameEngine` into an abstract class and made all 
classes that inherit from it implement methods to decide when cells should die or
reborn. When my game is starting, I have this code:

```
def addGameMode(gameMode:GameEngine) {
  modes += gameMode
}

addGameMode(ConwayEngine)
addGameMode(EasyMode)
addGameMode(HighLife)
addGameMode(Seeds)
```

And my classes that depends on the `GameEngine` rule receives it as a 
construct parameter. When I need to change the game rule, I use an setter method, like
the code below:

```
class GameView( var gameEngine: GameEngine, modes: MutableList[GameEngine] ) extends JFXApp {
...
  def setGameEngine(g: GameEngine) {
    gameEngine = g
  }
...
}
```

I don't know if this approach is correct but, from what I learned, the dependency
injection is correct. But, for my teacher, it isn't. And there my problems began.
According to him, the dependency should be declared in a .xml file and treated by
an external lib. He recommended `Spring` but I don't know how I should implement
the dependency injection in simple Scala + SBT project using a web framework.
Hopefully, I can ignore this recommendation to use `Spring` and use another lib.
I found [MacWire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire) but I don't know how to use it
to solve this problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: You say your implementation of DI is correct . But I don't see hat happens if I create an instance of GameView. How the program will initialize gamEngine and modes? And what happens if one of them has not been yet constructed? BTW, you can also look at Guice(https://github.com/google/guice) as a DI framework.

Comment: The setter for `gameEngine` is unnecessary because it's already a public `var`, which means that Scala conveniently defines a `gameEngine_=` setter method for you and you can just write `gameView.gameEngine = ...`. (And no, making it private and adding a `setGameEngine` method is *not* good Scala style.) But I agree, it probably doesn't make sense to pull in Spring just to use it as a DI framework.